# How to know on what item I click?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am using ejs to bild an online shop. I have a page with goods. When I click on one of the goods I want to get info about what item I clicked on. I have info of goods in my database. And to get this info i need to know on which of the goods I click. How do I do that?

```
HERE IS MY CODE OF PAGE WITH GOODS

   <div class="goods">
      <% const array = goods.items %>
      <% array.forEach (function (name) { %>
            <% const imgName = name.code %>

            <div class="item">
                  <a href="/goodsDescription/<%= folderName %>/<%=  imgName  %>"><img class="image" src="/img/<%= folderName %>/<%=  imgName  %>.jpg"></a>
                  <h3 class="product-title"><%=  name.name  %></h3>
                  <p class="product-price__current"><%= name.price %>₴</p>
                  <button class="buy-btn">Buy</button>
            </div>
      <% }) %>
      </div>
```

Comment: Attach an event listener function with each item you want to *listen* click on. Use *event* argument of the function to know which item was clicked using some unique id or other custom attribute (eg data-product-id) on the tag. Suggested Documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Comment: You can add an event listener for the click event to each div and use `event.target` to retrieve the element you clicked on. It would be something like: `document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (event) => { // here you can refer to the element either via event.target or item or this } ))`

Answer (score 0):

You can access it through a `data-attribute` via `e.target.dataset`

```
<div class="goods">
  <% const array = goods.items %>
  <% array.forEach (function (name) { %>
        <% const imgName = name.code %>

        <div class="item" data-id="<%= id %>">
              <a href="/goodsDescription/<%= folderName %>/<%=  imgName  %>" target="_blank"><img class="image" src="/img/<%= folderName %>/<%=  imgName  %>.jpg"></a>
              <h3 class="product-title"><%=  name.name  %></h3>
              <p class="product-price__current"><%= name.price %>₴</p>
              <button class="buy-btn">Buy</button>
        </div>
  <% }) %>
  </div>

<script>
  $('.item').addEventListener('click', e => {
    let id = e.target.dataset.id
    let photoclicked = e.target.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
})
</script>
```

Comment: and in this way I can use the id to know what picture was clicked on and use it afterwords?

Comment: answer updated to get the image source. Note that I made the image HREF target="_blank" - otherwise the current page would change URLs

Comment: Okey. But why do i need both let id .... and let photoclicked? Isn't having one of them enough?

Answer (score -1):

```
  <div class="goods">
  <% const array = goods.items %>
  <% array.forEach (function (name) { %>
        <% const imgName = name.code %>

        <div class="item<%= id %>">
              <a href="/goodsDescription/<%= folderName %>/<%=  imgName  %>"><img class="image" src="/img/<%= folderName %>/<%=  imgName  %>.jpg"></a>
              <h3 class="product-title"><%=  name.name  %></h3>
              <p class="product-price__current"><%= name.price %>₴</p>
              <button class="buy-btn">Buy</button>
        </div>
  <% }) %>
  </div>

<script>
  $('.item<%= id %>').addEventListner('click', ()=>{
    // do it here
})
</script>
```